# I got engaged while on an ESTA visa

Tags: visas, usa, europe, portugal

Alright, in the event of me and my boyfriend (he is a US citizen) getting married before the 90 days from my ESTA visa expiring, and if we apply for a change of status, can I stay in the us while the paperwork is being analysed? Or am I required to leave? If so, is there another visa i could get temporarily?

We got engaged during my visit, and the goal is to stay together but it came as a surprise and after two years of visits and long distance (he lived in Sweden, me in Portugal) we're honestly tired of being apart for long periods of time and ready to settle down.

Comment: I think you can stay, but you will probably get a proper answer shortly.

Comment: simplest thing is to ask someone at city hall where you're getting married. I'm sure they either know the answer or know where to ask (phone number for immigration maybe).

Comment: Congratulations :) for marriage and new life

Comment: @jwenting municipal workers are administrative extremely unlikely to know anything about immigration law.  But this is definitely a question for [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: You can adjust your status, but there is some kind of 30-60-90 day rule where you have to overcome the presumption that you knew about this before entering the US, essentially. I don't know much about US immigration law and cannot provide a good answer. I'm sure someone else will elaborate on this soon. Congratulations!

Comment: @lafemmecosmique the ever-knowledgeable user102008 recently pointed out to me that that rule is a Department of State rule related to the issue of visas so unless there's a similar rule at DHS that may not be a problem.  But having evidence that it truly was a surprise probably will be necessary.

Comment: A quick point on terminology: an ESTA is not a visa, but an authorization to attempt to enter the United States under the Visa Waiver Program (VWP). This does not really change the applicable procedures for you, however.

Comment: Obligatory: ESTA is not a visa. ESTA is the name of the system that implements the Visa Waiver Program that leads to you not needing a visa at all (provided you apply and qualify). The word "ESTA" is also used as a noun to describe the authorisation you receive as a result of that application, and/or to describe the piece of paper/email that proves said authorisation (as in _"I have an ESTA"_ and _"Here's my ESTA"_).

Comment: Welcome new user - you ***will have to get*** an immigration lawyer.  It's a scam but there it is.  It's going to cost you a couple grand all up.  Getting an immigration lawyer in the US, is like, finding an overweight person in the US  :)  :)  So quickly google up a local, well-regarded immigration lawyer.  The rest is just signing forms when told to and driving to various cities for annoying meetings / fingerprinting / etc.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit even "implements the visa waiver program" is rather overstating it (since the VWP existed for a couple of decades before ESTA).  It's more precise to say that ESTA is a system that VWP travelers must use to determine their eligibility to use the program (that's essentially what the law says, anyway, at [8 USC 1187(1)(11)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1187#a_11).

Comment: @phoog yes, but are likely to know where to go for answers better than some random people on the internet. And in my experience, though maybe not always the fastest or most proficient, tend to be helpful and resourceful.

Comment: @jwenting the proposition that municipal workers in the US would be likely even to know who to talk to about this strikes me as highly questionable indeed. The NYC office where I live has a pamphlet for foreigners about getting the marriage certificate legitimized because NYC is a popular destination for weddings.  I'll call and ask and see what they say.  The best answer I can imagine is "ask USCIS," which is what I thought your comment should have said.

Answer (score 14):

Knowing someone who did exactly this in the US very recently, I can say that it is possible to change your status once you are married without having to leave. However the law around it is not clear or simple and you should absolutely definitely talk to an immigration lawyer before attempting this. It's very easy to do something, or fail to do something, that would mean you didn't qualify and were overstaying your VWP limits, causing you lots of problems in the future.

My understanding is that you not only need to be married, but also to have filed the paperwork for the status change, before your VWP period expires. But your lawyer will know, so listen to them not me.

Do not ask a city hall official. There is no reason why they would know immigration law.

Comment: Immediate relatives can apply to adjust status even if they are out of status, but it is certainly better to apply before the 90 days expire rather than after, in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 3):

After the marriage, you would be in the Immediate Relative category (spouse, parent, or unmarried under-21 child of a US citizen). Immediate Relatives are eligible for Adjustment of Status in the US even if they entered on the Visa Waiver Program (whereas other categories cannot do AOS from VWP). So yes, you can stay and apply for Adjustment of Status. If you do Adjustment of Status, you cannot leave the US until you get your green card or an Advance Parole, or you will automatically abandon your AOS. The only issue with AOS from VWP is that people who entered on VWP waived any right to a hearing before being deported (except when claiming asylum), so in the unlikely case where the AOS is denied in error, you don't get to challenge the denial in removal proceedings.

Comment: If the AOS were denied, then, would there be any remedy available?